# Requests from Facebook IPs on Server

Tags: facebook, ads

We are running some ads through Facebook's Ads Manager.

We get requests on our server from Facebook IP addresses that don't show up as clicks in the Ad Manager.

We were wondering if this is due to Facebook rerouting traffic through their servers or if Facebook uses some kind of crawler to test the pages linked to in ads?

For our internal stats, we want to be counting real visits only.

Answer (score 0):

Yes facebook does use crawlers to fetch the content from the page. As well alternatively, take a keen look at the URL parameters that get embedded when a real click is done. You can test the same by noting down your IP Address, clicking on the link, then in your logs, inspect the request for 2 things:

- URL Parameters
- Referer Header

Using the combination of the above 2, you can monitor the actual clicks and facebook crawler requests. As well User-Agent is another good indication.

If you want to filter based on IP Addresses, you can find all the Facebook IP Addresses from the Github repo which I have created and gets updated daily !

Link: [Facebook IP Addresses](https://github.com/aarvee11/FacebookIPLists)

Do let me know in case of any further queries !